# VPN ports not opening on ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewall, openvpn

Im trying to set up an openvpn on my pc (which is running Ubuntu Server 22.04). I've used the quick install script listed [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-linux-14-04-or-16-04-lts/)

When i try to connect on my linux machine i get the following error:

```
2022-05-01 00:41:54 read UDP [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
```

Which means that my port isn't open. I tried opening it with ufw and the guide listed on another similar problem:
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413705/openvpn-connection-refused-code-111)

The mini server is on my local network with a static ip.
Doing `sudo nmap -sU localhost`

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000075s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on localhost (127.0.0.1) are closed

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.33 seconds
```

Even tho i allowed the port with ufw. `sudo ufw status`:

```
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1194/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
1194/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Also my netplan config (just in case):

```
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      access-points:
        NETSSID:
          password: 'pass'
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.101/24]
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
```

Comment: Did you verify that an openvpn process is actually running?